# Can I create an alternative for not operator `!`

Tags: c#

I think `!` is a very small sign to make the condition having negative meaning. Can I use some alternative for that or create my own keyword (I would like to use `not`, but if it is reserved keyword anything is ok.).

Comment: Instead of `if (!a.Contains(b))` you can write `if (a.Contains(b) == false)`. But you cannot create new operator.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, I think he is asking whether he can define a keyword with the same meaning, which would function like the keyword `not` in Python.

Comment: Dot operator `.` is even smaller than this. You may consider replacing that also.

Comment: If you really want you could make a function called `not(x)` that returns `!x`.

Comment: Or use `!!!`. It looks stupid but is functionally equivalent to `!` and three times larger.

Comment: or use `!!!!!` or use `!!!!!!!` or use any other odd digit `!`

Comment: @Juhana: Then `!!!!!` will be five times larger ;)

Comment: I would imagine you'd be better off just using a larger font size, looking into custom code highlighting, or just not worry about it, if your code is formatted well enough it should be clear when you are using `!` what you are trying to do

Comment: @Juhana Both suggestions are appreciated :) thx

Comment: Thanks all, I decided to change the color of the operators.

Comment: @serdar: Good decision!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `!`. Its the conventional and simplest way to [perform logical negation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691367%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in C#.

You could obviously do whatever you like for yourself, but:

1. other libraries/code still use `!`
2. if some other people run across your code they will get confused (and probably still use `!` when editing your code).

Answer (score 0):

I don`t think it would be a good approach but i can suggest adding extension method to bool type.
It would look like this

```
public static class BoolExtentions
{
    public static bool Not(this bool self)
    {
        return !self;
    }
}
```